# How to create a field_collection_item using the RESTful Web Services API in DRUPAL 8

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-8, hal-json, drupal-field-collection

I have installed RESTful Web Services on my Drupal 8 site, I activated the field_collection_item resource (/field_collection_item/{field_collection_item}) with all the methods available (GET, POST, etc with authentication:basic_auth, cookie and formats:hal_json, json).

I have a content-type with a field collection in it (name:field_field_collection). In order to create a new node of this content-type, I have to create the field collection item first but I can not succeed because I get 403 Forbidden even though I'm properly authenticating onto the system.

My **request URL** is : http://my_server.com/entity/field_collection_item?_format=hal_json (POST).

The header of the request is :

```
 POST /entity/field_collection_item?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1
Host: my_server.com
X-CSRF-Token: P1Z8fnxb0-tTR3CLqNJMSDnU_DQDFnt2ko0Jnitwsd0
Authorization: Basic my_user:my_password
Content-Type: application/hal+json
```

The **body** of my request is :

```
{  
  "_links": {
      "type": { "href":"http://my_server.com/rest/type/field_collection_item/field_field_collection" }
  },
  "field_text1":[{"value": "1111"}],
  "field_text2":[{"value": "2222"}],
  "field_name":[{"target_id": "field_field_collection"}]  
   }
}
```

field_field_collection is the name of my field_collection entity. field_text1, field_text2 are the text fields of my collection.

When I make the request with POSTMAN or DHC I get **403 Forbidden** response.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong? Is there another way that this request can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the endpoints permissions?

It sounds like you have setup the REST resource correct.. but you also have to set the permissions so anon users can access it.